# WordPress Toolbar: NO SHOW for specific users while on index page

Tags: wordpress, toolbar

I would like to show the toolbar to all visitors of my site, with the exception of; not logged in users\visitors, while on the index page.

The following placed in my function file works fine for displaying the toolbar to all visitors at all times.

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '**__return_true**' );

So I was hoping replacing that with something like this could meet my added conditions...

```
    function show_bar() {
         if ( ! isset( $show_admin_bar ) ) {
              if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_home() ) {
                   $show_admin_bar = __return_false;
              } else {
                   $show_admin_bar = __return_true;           }
         }
   $show_admin_bar = add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '$show_admin_bar' );
   return $show_admin_bar;
    }
```

I don't think the function is being fired (No warnings or errors, but no toolbar for visitors. ). My question is, Is there a better way to do this, if not what would it take to get this function to work?

thx

Comment: I believe is_home() can be a problem sometimes, try (is_home() || is_front_page()).  I'd also try removing the is_home() check all together and see if it's the !is_user_logged_in() that's causing the problem.

Comment: I`function show_bar() {
             
      $show_admin_bar = __return_true;           
       $show_admin_bar_please = add_filters( 'show_admin_bar', '$show_admin_bar' ) ;
   return $show_admin_bar_please;
    
 }`

Comment: I simplified the function just to see if I could get the toolbar to display and ended up with the same negative results. The function is being ignored for some reason.

Comment: Ah. Try removing the single quotes in add_filters( 'show_admin_bar', '$show_admin_bar' ) ;

Comment: No Dice Daniel, The hard truth is, If I just add the line I said works for showing the toolbar to everybody inside a function (with or without a return statement) the function gets ignored. I think I might need to figure out how to show_admin_bar as an action, so it gets acted on. Then I can set my conditions up.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused lol, do you mean that you're not actually calling the function (similar to the line 'show_bar();' function anywhere? If so then you'll definitely need to insert that somewhere, most likely in the WordPress template's header file.